# Extract Full Html Source , not partial

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control, extract, html-agility-pack

I am trying to extract images and some text off the following site http://bit.ly/16jFeyA

Web Form , C# , Visual Studio, HtmlAgilityPack

Encoding Works well with WebClient Only , browser `wb.Document.Encoding = "GB2312";` doesn't work, Not important.

The site uses Lazy Load, for images. The WebBrowser Loads properly, with the images with info but when i extract using either web client / wb.DocumentText , it will not download the "full information" some information are missing especially the images links etc.

Is there anyway around this? I am trying to extract images and product info.

Extracted using wb.DocumentText after scrolling down to force image to load(due to lazy load) - http://notepad.cc/share/EjW3tFCffO

wb = webBrowser

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something which knows how to evaluate and execute client-side JavaScript, such as a headless browser. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that, currently found a solution which is to develop extensions to get the data i need and save images.